# how to make a theme switcher using the jQuery mobile's data-theme attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, data-theme

I want to make a theme switcher using the `data-theme` attribute of the jQuery mobile framework. When the user clicks a link which has a data-theme inside it, all my pages' `data-theme` attribute should be replaced with this clicked `data-theme` attribute. To get a better idea of what I'm trying to do [see this](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/pages-themes.html) page at the jQuery mobile site, it's pretty close to what I'm trying to do for my pages except that it only updates the current page, and I want to update all of the webApp pages.

Comment: You cannot just update the `data-theme` attributes and expect the theme to change. You have to then re-initialize every widget on the page so it gets the proper classes/structure.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change theme dynamically in jquery mobile?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8656801/how-to-change-theme-dynamically-in-jquery-mobile)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set data-theme="THEME_LETTER" as a php variable. Then, have links on the page to switch themes. When the user clicks a link for theme "b", it will set a session variable, and then on each page load, the THEME_LETTER will be set by php to reflect their selection.

inside the HTML, it would look like this:

data-theme="`<?php echo $_SESSION['THEME_LETTER']; ?>`"

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at jquery ui theme roller?, it's available for Jquery Mobile too

http://jquerymobile.com/themeroller/

generate a set of themes and switch it accordingly.
Here's a link on switching:
http://midnightprogrammer.net/post/Change-Page-Themes-Dynamically-Using-JQuery-Theme-Roller.aspx

Comment: is that mechanism will work for all my webApp pages, i.e. will update all the pages in the App or only update one page?

Comment: isn't exist a mechanism which will update only the data-theme attribute of all the pages when a data-theme link is clicked, i'm sure it can be done, but don't know how to do it by javascript!